# How to design an API that returns nested lists?

Tags: java, collections

I am retrieving GeoPoints from a database and organize them for usage in frontend. The GeoPoints are aggregated  in segments, the segments in layers, the layers are mapped to drive ids and that map is maped to car ids. The frontend displays all of that nicely, with Tooltips and such.

My REST GetMapping method looks like this.

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<List<List<double[]>>>>>>
```

For new colleagues, this is insanely hard to understand. But I can't think of any other way to do it. Should I create dummy child classes of `Map` and `List` just so I can write something like

```
public ResponseEntity<CarMap<Integer, DriveMap<Integer, Layers<Segments<GeoPoints<double[]>>>>>>
```

How is something like this handled typically?

Comment: `But I can't think of any other way to do it. ` You can. Imagine yourself how would you implement the client for such abomination.

Comment: are the geopoints really `double[]`, or are they actually a (lat, long) pair? (or (lat, long, height) triple). And there is *no* metadata about the segments or layers?

Comment: @Caleth they could be a pair, but they are just being taken out from the database and then included in the response. And since the dataset can be fairly big, additional transforming shoould probably avoided. No there, is  no metadata for segments and layers. Simply accumulators ( aka lists)

Comment: What's the structure of the database? I would expect it to be able to populate a simple DTO from the column set. How does the DB know into which segment and layer a measurement goes?

Comment: @Caleth database table is plain rows of drive-id/lat/long/time values. Those are selected that are visible in the desired viewport. Then, backend iterates through them. When the drive goes outside of the viewport, a new layer is created. When the time difference between two points is higher than expected, a record gap is assumed and next points are mapped on a new segment. Hope that is not too confusing. In short: processing of waypoints depending on input parameters. Cheers

Comment: Sounds like the start and end timepoint of a segment might be useful. ditto the viewport of a layer. And my point is that a (lat, long) pair is what is coming out of the database, not a arbitrary length sequence of doubles

Comment: @Caleth ok I see. And regardless of whether start/end-times are useful (I dont think they would, but I dont want to go beyond the scope of this comment section) - putting it in classes like below answer would be the way to go, you say?

Comment: Yes. I was just exploring the possible members of such classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For new colleagues, this is insanely hard to understand

Yeah, no kidding. I'm surprised anyone understands it.

Why are you not using actual classes?

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Car>> myMethod { ... }

class Car
{
    private final int id;
    private final List<Drive> drives;
}

class Drive
{
    private final int id;
    private final List<Layer> layers;
}

class Layer
{
    private final List<Segment> segments;
}

class Segment
{
    private final List<GeoPoint> geopoints;
}

class GeoPoint
{
    private final List<Double> points;
}
```